# Make string operations on field in mongodb collection (Aggregation & regex)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using a collection in Mongo with a price field with multiple money type :

```
{
  price: '15 gp' // 15 gold pieces
}
```

or

```
{
  price: '4 sp' // 0.4 gold pieces
}
```

I'm looking for a way to modify this field before querying the collection.

For example doing string modifications to remove the `gp/sp` and doing math operations to have a correct price in "GP" (1 GP = 10 SP)

This would help ordering the collection since mongo can't understand that 10 sp < 2 gp.

Is there a way to use Aggregation and regex to do it ?

Comment: You can try using the `$replaceOne` aggregate operator (MongoDB v5.x).

Comment: `$replaceOne` would replace the whole document with an other. I'm looking for a way to "format" the price field to remove the "gp", "sp" and use the same money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add new field as `rate` and check the gp or sp and put rate of each price for  example sp have rate of 10 and gp have rate of 1
then add universalprice field with multiply of rate of price and value of price
after that you could compare price

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$split": [
          "$price",
          ","
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      price: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$newField",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "rate": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$price",
                  "regex": ".*gp*."
                }
              },
              "then": "1"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$price",
                  "regex": ".*sp*."
                }
              },
              "then": "10"
            }
          ],
          default: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      price: 1,
      universalPrice: {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$toInt": "$rate"
          },
          {
            "$toInt": {
              $first: {
                "$split": [
                  "$price",
                  " "
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/S5EIUdWRp5W

Comment: This solution is working for basic integers like `5 gp`, thought I'm having issues with numbers with a thousand separator like `4,500 gp`. Is there a filter to remove the `,` ?

Comment: ok let me update my asnwer

Comment: my answer has been updated

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there a way to keep all fields from the initial collection ? (not only `price`) ?

Comment: Could you explain with example?

Comment: My collection has multiple fields, not just `price`. I would like to keep them all with the additional `universalPrice`.
Example : 
`{ name: "Object X", type: "weapon", price: "150,00,00 gp"}`

Comment: In last $project object add other key what you want like price:1 for example name:1 type:1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation stage to convert the `price` field value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          price: {
              $function: {
                  body: function(inPrice) {
                               let outPrice;
                               if (/gp/.test(inPrice)) {
                                   outPrice = parseInt(inPrice.replace("gp", "").trim()) * 10;
                               }
                               else if (/sp/.test(inPrice)) {
                                   outPrice = parseInt(inPrice.replace("sp", "").trim());
                               }
                               else {
                                   outPrice = inPrice; // whatever needs here...
                               }
                               return outPrice;
                  },
                  args: [ "$price" ],
                  lang: "js"
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

For example, `price: "5 gp"` will convert to `price: 50` *and* `price: "12 sp"` will convert to `price: 12`. Note the values are converted to number type fields for comparison and also calculations.